# What MySQL storage engine i should on MMO/Multiplayer game?

Tags: mysql

I don't know which engine would give best performance for my database queries.

My server is doing parametrized queries to database and queries are not big.

I wan't to hear your opinion !

Engines

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz1SU.png]

Comment: Please elaborate more on your needs.

Comment: BLACKHOLE is definitely the fastest. Pick BLACKHOLE.

Comment: Don't use `Blackhole`, `Memory` or `CSV`. If you read more than you write, use `MyISAM`. Otherwise, `InnoBD`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel BLACKHOLE is perfect if you don't have much disk space, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree, but everything that goes in, won't come back out.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/992/401/e37.png

Answer (score 1):

For the vast majority of purposes, InnoDB is the correct choice. Use it.

Most of other options listed in your screenshot are either special-purpose storage engines which are not suitable for general use (MEMORY, EXAMPLE, FEDERATED, ARCHIVE, CSV, and BLACKHOLE), or are not available in standard builds of MySQL (most of the rest, e.g. InifiniDB, Brighthouse, and TokuDB).

The lone exception is MyISAM, which is an older MySQL storage engine which does not support transactions, is more prone to corruption, and generally tends to perform worse than InnoDB. There is generally no reason to use it in current builds of MySQL.

Comment: I disagree about MyISAM. MyISAM is faster than InnoBD on **reading** due to it's simpler "architecture". InnoBD is generally safer and faster for writting.